# EC2 elastic IP access on the browser times out

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, iptables

http://elastic-ip-address/ times out but http://public-DNS-name-instance/ works and brings up the web page.

1. elastic IP address is already mapped to the instance I am running.
2. I have modified iptables to accept all traffic on port 80
3. instance is running under a security group that allows http traffic on port 80

here is the output of my iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

How do I get http:/// to work and bring up the web page returned by the web server?

Thanks!

Comment: stop iptables and try access it again.

Comment: I tried sudo service iptables stop. it flushed out the rules. but the browser access and ip pings are both still timing out. is there another way to stop iptables?

Comment: ah! figured out..i had rebooted the instance. and elastic IP association was lost. I had to reassociate it and now it all works. thanks.

Comment: hahaha! you got to be more observing...